# Asymptotic rate of decrease of error function

Tags: asymptotics, normal-distribution, uniform-convergence, error-function

The [complementary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) is defined as
$$
\text{erfc}(x) = 1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{x} e^{-t^2} dt
$$
and is related to the Gaussian (Normal) distribution. Is there an approximation of the form $\exp(g(x))$ that converges to $\phi(x)$ asymptotically? i.e. can we find $g(x)$ such that
$$
\underset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \frac{\exp(g(x))}{\text{erfc}(x)} = 1
$$
and that $\exp(g(x))$ "approximates" $\text{erfc}(x)$ in some sense when $x$ is large but not infinite?

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\exp(g(x))}{\phi(x)}=1 $ ?

Comment: I suppose that's a better way to put it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, shouldn't $\phi$ be defined as $\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \int_0^{x} \operatorname e^{-t^2} \operatorname d t $ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Asymptotic_expansion

Comment: Since  $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \phi(x)=1 $, we could just take any continous function $g(x)$ such that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} g(x)= 0$, right?

Comment: Correct, but I'm looking for something that is approximately correct for large $x$ also. What's a good way to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one asymptotic expansion in the Handbook of Mathematical functions and also listed in your link; it is not quite in the form you wanted but close.

If 
$$\text{erfc}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_z^\infty e^{-t^2}~ dt = 1 - \text{erf}(z)$$
then
$$\text{erfc}(z)\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-z^2} \cdot 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty 
 (-1)^k~\frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}k! } \cdot \frac{1}{z^{2k+1}}
$$
as $z\to\infty$, $\lvert \arg z \rvert < 3\pi/4. $

This can be adapted to the required form;  for example, the first term is,
$$\text{erfc}(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt \pi} e^{-z^2}\cdot \frac{1}{z} = e^{-z^2-\log(z\sqrt{\pi})}$$
which gives $g(z) = -z^2-\log(z\sqrt{\pi})$.

Comment: It says on the Wiki page that the series diverges. However, it seems that you consider it bounded. Is that the meaning of $|\arg z| < 3\pi/4$. If so, how did that come about?

Comment: The series diverges, but it does satisfy the asymptotic test of @SewerKeeper, that the ratio of a finite number of terms to $\text{erfc}$ has limit $1$ as $z \to \infty$ with restriction on the path a complex $z$ may take.  Moreover, the absolute error from a finite number of terms initially decreases.  The express error term is on the Wikipedia link, and you will see then the series can be as accurate as you like if $z$ is large enough; it is useful way of approximating $\text{erfc}$ for larger arguments but note tighter restrictions are needed on $\arg z$.